# How to make EditText be related to each other in Android Sturdio

Tags: java, android, xml, variables

What I have in my Layout are six `EditText`(Only for numbers), and when I run the program I notice
that when I put a number in the first `EditText` it leads me to the other one(The other `EditText`) by pressing 'next', but when I put the number in the second, instead of 'next' it says 'Done'. I want all the six to be related, starting from the first one an the button 'Done' to appear only in the last one. I think this is something you do in the xml file of the Layout, but I don't know what.

Comment: try `android:nextFocusDown` like `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/nextId"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` in the xml for your EditText.

This should do the trick. I had a problem earlier where I was getting a return sign instead of "done" or "next". The `singleLine` attribute for the EditText fixed that.